Questions about resources for learning chinese
Should questions asking for resources for learning chinese be allowed? (I asked one myself...)  This type of question will tend towards simple answers and could have lots of repeat slightly overlapping answers.

I don't mind questions like: "What are some good quality podcasts?" I think there would only be a few and they are not so easy to find.
So I would be in favour of asking these types of questions on the site if we can come up with good quality answers.
As long as the questions don't ask for personal opionion like why is book X better than book Y.

This type of questions is normal in this early stage of a SE site, so they shouldn't worry. 
But they are a one-time questions, which means that future visitors will use them and not ask more. I think that in a while from now, they should be considered simple duplicates.

It can be included in FAQ section. Maybe now is a bit early for FAQ.

My thought on this is that it would be good to get a bunch of meta questions going for this type of question.  This would both satisfy the people who benefit from that type of question and it wouldn't clog up the rest of the site.

We should make a FAQ to collect this kind of information as soon as possible for the beginning learners to advantage ones. Besides this, everyone can take part in this by editing, removing some useless to maintain that.
If possible, when you enter this forum, a pop-up window will show you to tell you "If you wanna find more resources to learn Chinese, please go to here"——Here's just the link to refer the references we've found.....
